# GAS Loop goes indefinite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Problem:-
I need to get Name and ID of the latest created document from some Google Drive folders.

Solution:-
I wasn’t able to find an easy way to get it, hence, created a loop for files within the folder to get max date - then loop again in folder to match the date and Log the name and date – the below code (when commented as mentioned) works properly for the solution.

Instead of rewriting the whole code with just a different folder name, I tried creating a loop for folder name as well.

However app script goes into infinite loop giving out the Maximum execution time limit message.
Any help appreciated.

```
function Get_lastestdate() {

  //Define Spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PEOPLE");

  //comment from here to work properly
  for (var i =1; i < 4; i++) {

  if (i = 1) { var foldername = "Folder1"}
  if (i = 2) { var foldername = "Folder2"}
  if (i = 3) { var foldername = "Folder3"}
  // till here

  //Define folder and files
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(foldername); //set folder name in case commenting.
  var lastfile = folder.getFiles();

  //Make a blank array
  var noofdaysarray = []
  var yeararray = []

  //Loop to get all No of days in a year & the year
  for (var i in lastfile) {
  noofdaysarray.push(Utilities.formatDate(lastfile[i].getDateCreated(),"GMT","D"));
  yeararray.push(Utilities.formatDate(lastfile[i].getDateCreated(),"GMT","y"));
  }

  //Get the max date from date and year
  var largestdate = Math.max.apply(Math, noofdaysarray);
  var largestyear = Math.max.apply(Math, yeararray);
  //Get maximum available date
  var matchcriteria = largestdate + largestyear

  //Again loop for matching criteria with the actual date uploaded
  for (var i in lastfile) {
  var lastdate = Utilities.formatDate(lastfile[i].getDateCreated(),"GMT","D");
  var lastyear = Utilities.formatDate(lastfile[i].getDateCreated(),"GMT","y");
  var wholedate = parseInt(lastdate) + parseInt(lastyear); //parseInt is for converting text to number

  //Get doc name if both dates matches
  if (wholedate == matchcriteria) {
  Logger.log(lastfile[i].getId());
  Logger.log(lastfile[i].getName());
  }
  }
 } //comment this as a part of loop

}
```

Between:- If there's an easier way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: I think that you will do better with DriveApp.folder.searchfiles https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles(String) to get files since last run, then iterate though those

Answer (score 1):

Dont use "i" in both inner and outer loops.  that will be a problem.

wouldn't it be easier to do something like this so you only do one loop?

```
var mostRecentDate = new Date(2000,01,01);
var fileName="";
var fileId="";

for(var i = 1; i<5; i++){

   var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Folder'+i);
   var files = folder.getFiles();
   for(var j in files) {
      if(files[j].getDateCreated()>mostRecentDate){  //or getLastUpdated
         mostRecentDate=files[j].getDateCreated();
         fileName=files[j].getName();
         fileId=files[j].getId();
       }

    }
}
Logger.log("File: " + filename + " Id: " + fileId + " Created: " + mostRecentDate);
```

You may need to do paging if you have a huge number of files & folders to iterate through.

Comment: Thanks, I added var fileId=""; on 3row, however the log shows "[13-12-17 18:51:40:040 IST] File:  Id:  Created: Tue Feb 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)", I also tried chagning new Date to todays date (just in case) but still the same message with different created date.

Comment: I didn't test this code - change the if(files.getDateCreated... to if(files[j].getDateCreated...

Comment: The code doesnt work as required but up for, bringing i variable used twive for attention.

Comment: One other bug... files[j].getDateCreated should have been files[j].getDateCreated()  - I was missing the parens on the getDateCreated function.  that's what you get when you just start typing sudo-code and make it too close to the real thing lol

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot find function getDateCreated in object File,File,File" on "mostRecentDate=files.getDateCreated();" line

Comment: Another bug you have is using if (i=1) which assigns instead of comparing. Its in many places in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DocsList to retrieve the last modified files. you told that you want the last created but maybe the last modified can be usefull. Check the code bellow:

```
function findLastModified() {
     //Retrieve folder
     var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U");

     //Ask for 5 files
     var numberOfFiles = 5;

     //The first parameter is the search query, in this case we want all files
     var filesResult = folder.findForPaging("", 5);

     //By Default they will be sorted by last modified date
     var files = filesResult.getFiles();

     Logger.log("Found "+files.length+" files");

     //Iterate
     for(var x in files) {
       var file = files[x];
       Logger.log(file.getLastUpdated());
      }
    }
```

Live version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1quq7ioXu1gJ97HTuzNQC9IpsnWf4_SFyEPC0Xv2XmQSdm23EcwpTvDFC/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: Nice, this seems to work, but what does 5 in ask for 5 files means; I mean will the code only look at 5 files, in this case it can be an issue if files are more than five, right?

Comment: the 5 is the paging size. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/folder#findForPaging(String,Integer,Token)   It should not be an issue because it is looking at the first 5 of an already sorted list.  (But by modified date not created date)

Comment: Not working with some folder, attached is the [Execution Transcript](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9u_K1HbgiEKamJhQjdwdzdZMk0/edit?usp=sharing) any particular reason. It has 3 Google Presentation.

Comment: Should work with all, you only changed the folder id? What kind of files are within it?

Comment: Yes, changed only the id, there are three Google Presentation, all of them uploaded at the same date (is that an issue?), on another folder I have 4 xls file?

Comment: What's the length of files variable? Can you post the log output?

Comment: Sorry, I commented that line, when uncomment it says 0 files found, but there are 3 Google Presentations in it.

Comment: in the first argumento of function findForPaging try to put the name of one presentation and tell us the result

Comment: Ok, When I add the start word for each report (same), as ("RAG", 5), the logger says found 3 files, and list names of three files. (changed last line to Logger.log(file.getName());)

Comment: Put "?" as parameter like ("?", 5) an tell us the result.